# Flashing Esp32 using Raspberrypi GPIO via openocd (JTAG connection)

Tags: esp32, openocd, jtag

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZoJV.png)I am trying to program esp32 with Rpi GPIO's with JTAG connections using the command: `sudo /opt/openocd/src/openocd -f interface/rpi2.cfg -c "adapter speed 1000" -f target/esp32.cfg -c "program file-path/file.bin 0x10000 verify reset exit" -s /opt/openocd/tcl/`

```
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.12.0+dev-00248-g56fd04832 (2023-07-06-15:49)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
DEPRECATED! use 'adapter gpio swclk; adapter gpio swdio' not 'bcm2835gpio_swd_nums'
DEPRECATED! use 'adapter gpio tck; adapter gpio tms; adapter gpio tdi; adapter gpio tdo' not 'bcm2835gpio_jtag_nums'
adapter speed: 1000 kHz
force hard breakpoints
Info : BCM2835 GPIO JTAG/SWD bitbang driver
Info : clock speed 995 kHz
Info : JTAG tap: esp32.cpu0 tap/device found: 0x120034e5 (mfg: 0x272 (Tensilica), part: 0x2003, ver: 0x1)
Info : JTAG tap: esp32.cpu1 tap/device found: 0x120034e5 (mfg: 0x272 (Tensilica), part: 0x2003, ver: 0x1)
Info : starting gdb server for esp32.cpu0 on 3333
Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
Info : JTAG tap: esp32.cpu0 tap/device found: 0x120034e5 (mfg: 0x272 (Tensilica), part: 0x2003, ver: 0x1)
Info : JTAG tap: esp32.cpu1 tap/device found: 0x120034e5 (mfg: 0x272 (Tensilica), part: 0x2003, ver: 0x1)
Info : [esp32.cpu0] requesting target halt and executing a soft reset
Info : Set GDB target to 'esp32.cpu0'
Info : [esp32.cpu0] Debug controller was reset.
Info : [esp32.cpu0] Core was reset.
Info : [esp32.cpu1] requesting target halt and executing a soft reset
Info : [esp32.cpu0] Core was reset.
Info : [esp32.cpu1] Debug controller was reset.
Info : [esp32.cpu1] Core was reset.
** Programming Started **
  esp32 flashbootstrap none|1.8|3.3|high|low
    esp32.cpu0 esp32 flashbootstrap none|1.8|3.3|high|low
    esp32.cpu1 esp32 flashbootstrap none|1.8|3.3|high|low
flash
  flash bank bank_id driver_name base_address size_bytes chip_width_bytes
            bus_width_bytes target [driver_options ...]
  flash banks
  flash init
  flash list
gdb_flash_program ('enable'|'disable')
nand
program <filename> [address] [pre-verify] [verify] [reset] [exit]
** Programming Failed **
shutdown command invoked
embedded:startup.tcl:1563: Error: 
at file "embedded:startup.tcl", line 1563
```

So I am getting Programming failed and program command format. Is their any issue with the program command. Also it is showing error "embedded:startup.tcl:1563: Error:
at file "embedded:startup.tcl", line 1563".
Is their something I am missing?